# Change specific text and keep the rest

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I have field values that are:

- OG_S_G4,
- OG_S_G3,
- OG_S_G2, etc.

and I want to change the OG to LIP whilst keeping all the text after (i.e. LIP_S_G4), is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Create a new field with a type of text (string), and in the field calculator just use the following expression in a new field:

```
replace("fieldName",'OG','LIP')
```

where the `fieldName` is the name of the field that holds the texts `OG_S_G4, OG_S_G3, OG_S_G2`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column using the field calculator in the attribute table of your data.

[image]

Using the following code you can add new data labels based on existing ones.

```
CASE
  WHEN "column_name"= 'OG_SG4' THEN 'LIP_S_G4'
  WHEN "column_name"= 'OG_SG3' THEN 'LIP_S_G3'
  WHEN "column_name"= 'OG_SG2' THEN 'LIP_S_G2'
END
```

Make sure that you set the correct output field type, in this case "Text (string)".

[image]

Comment: Thank you to the two people who answered my question, really helped!!!!